# Word describing a slice of multi-dimensional space

Tags: terminology

I'm in the market for a mathematical (or otherwise) **term to describe a slice of a hypercube**.

*Tensor* is out of the running as that's the name of the object I am slicing.

The second I could use a hand with is a term to describe an index (or *access point*) that spans more than a single point in each dimension.

For example:

- **Regular index** [1, 2, 1] would access index 1 in dimension-one, index 2 in dimension-2 and index 1 in dimension-3
- **Spanning Index (or whatever)** [3->4, 1, 4->9] would access all elements between indices 3 and 4 of dimension-1, index 1 of dimension-2, etc...

Let me know if this is better suited in the Mathematics StackExchange.

Comment: "fractional tensor" or "tensor fraction" maybe?

Comment: A slice of a multi-dimensional space with more than three dimensions is a hyperplane. But that's not really a slice of a hypercube since a hyperplane is infinite while a hypercube is not. Anyway, better question for the Mathematics StackExchange for sure.

Comment: From Wikipedia: [*The central idea is that the visible, four-dimensional universe is restricted to a **brane** inside a higher-dimensional space, called the "bulk" (also known as "hyperspace").*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology) I understand that to mean the "brane" is a 4-d "slice" within a "hyperspace" of 5 dimensions or more.

Comment: If you could define what you mean by "tensor" and "slice of a hypercube" that would be helpful. The definitons I know of them have little relation to each other, which suggests that you may be using different definitions.

Comment: Is the word your looking for meant to restrict one dimension?  Such that [3->4,2->3,4->9] wouldn't be allowed?

Comment: Actually, this may be a suitable question for EL&U, but only if mathematics doesn't yet have such a term and we're coining a new term.  To know if we are we'd have to ask Mathematics StackExchange.

Comment: A 2d slice of a 3d object could be called a "cross-section".  Perhaps you could call a slice of a hypercube a "3d cross-section"?  Note that I'm not a mathematician, so it may not be technically correct.

Comment: @CandiedOrange A new word would be awesome. I've gone with Span for the subregion of the Tensor. But I still don't have an answer for the ranged index:  I would suggest "intractus" from intra - "within" & tractus - "space".

Comment: @MattSamuel By tensor I mean a multidimensional table, and by hypercube I refer to the shape such a table would take.

Comment: Are the slices you mention perpendicular to all the faces or can they be at different angles? (I'm guessing perpendicular since this is discrete.) Is a slice itself a tensor (of a different dimension)?

Comment: @MattSamuel they would be perpendicular to each other.

Comment: You could use "subtensor." Mathematically you could call array using only a subset of the indices a "projection," because that's what it is in the sense of linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about terminology, but let me try to formalize what I think you mean, in near-maximum generality. Perhaps this is really what you're looking for; if not, oh well.

This answer assumes a basic understanding of [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals). The second part assumes a basic understanding of [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) (in general), and the [product functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29) in particular.

---

> **Definition 0.** Suppose $X$ is a set and $\alpha$ is an $n$-long sequence of ordinals. Then an $X$-valued array of shape $\alpha$ is a function $X \leftarrow \prod_{i<n} \alpha_i.$

So for example, if $A$ is an $X$-valued array of shape $(3,4,5)$, then the value stored at $(1,2,1)$ is denoted $A(1,2,1)$, and this is an element of $X$.

Anyway, since arrays are just functions, we can use standard mathematical notation to get your "slices". For example, if $A$ has shape $(3,4,5)$, then $A(1,-,-)$ is the corresponding array of shape $(4,5)$ defined in the obvious way. So the two-dimensional "slices" obtained by choosing different values for the first index are

$$A(0,-,-) \qquad A(1,-,-) \qquad A(2,-,-)$$

and these are all $X$-valued arrays of shape $(4,5).$

---

Your second question is much more interesting. The amazing thing about ordinals is that the following definition makes sense:

> **Definition 1.** Suppose $\beta$ is an ordinal and $S$ is a subset of $\beta$. Then we write $\mathrm{ord}_S$ for the unique ordinal that is order-isomorphic to $S$, and we write $S^*$ for the unique such isomorphism $S \leftarrow \mathrm{ord}_S$.

The cool thing about this is the following. Suppose we're given an array $A$ of shape $(10,10,10).$ Suppose I'm interested in the "subarray" given by [3->4, 1, 4->9]. Well, this can be formally defined as:

$$A \circ ([3,4]^* \times [1]^* \times [4,9]^*)$$

where $\times$ is understood to be a functor in the usual way.